# Is there a way to make a class object represent itself by the variable name holding it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, repr

I have the following code, where the `info` parameter can be anything (str, int, list etc.):

```
class MyClass():
  def __init__(self, info):
    self.info = info

object_1 = MyClass("Whatever 1")
object_2 = MyClass("Whatever 2")
object_3 = MyClass("Whatever 3")

my_list = [object_1, object_2, object_3]

print(my_list)
```

If you run it, you will get the following result:

```
[<MyClass object at 0x7f**********>, <MyClass object at 0x7f**********>, <MyClass object at 0x7f**********>]
```

But I would like `print(my_list)` to print this:

```
[object_1, object_2, object_3]
```

Is there a way to do so, without adding another parameter to the `__init__` function definition (e.g. `def __init__(self, info, representation):`) and defining a `__repr__` returning its value (e.g. `return representation`)?

Comment: You want the variable names being displayed as the representation?!? What if the same object is being refernced by two different variables?

Comment: Just use the use the "another parameter to the `__init__` function definition". That's clear - and easy to use and maintain. All solutions that would link the variable name to the actual Python object will be fragile and not easy-to-use.

Comment: @MSeifert that's why I was asking "if it's possible to do so". Of course I could initially add another parameter to the __init__ but I also wanted to know if doing the thing I've asked about is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really recommend doing this, and I'm not sure about how to make it robust in the face of all sort of complications such as the class and the variables being in different modules, or having multiple bindings to the instances.

However, with all sorts of caveats, just for fun, here's a proof-of-concept which assumes that the class and its instances are bound in the same module

```
import sys

class Magic:

    def __repr__(self):
        module = sys.modules[self.__class__.__module__]
        for name, object_ in vars(module).items():
            if object_ is self:
                return name
        else:
            return '<name not found>'


apple  = Magic()
banana = Magic()
cherry = Magic()

fruit = [apple, banana, cherry]
print(fruit)
```

This gives the output

```
[apple, banana, cherry]
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as you want to create them outside of the current module (you mentioned that but I wanted to stress the point again). I actually wouldn't advise trying to encourage finding solutions for a problems that shouldn't be solved (at least not in the way the question asks for), even if they are fun.

Comment: @MSeifert ... which is why I started my answer by saying that I really do not recommend doing this, and implying that it's not not going to work across different modules.

Comment: @MSeifert :-) Agreed. Just to be sure: OP, trust us. You **do not want to do this**!

Comment: As soon as I remembered you can (do a stupid thing) refer to the same object using different variables I realized that it's impossible to do what I was asking for easily. Moreover, I initially stated "if there's a way to do so", which means that this is more of an interesting thing to have rather than a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2):

This would become very difficult to use if you have more than one reference to the same variable. Your best bet is to have some kind of Registry class that keeps track of all hashes of the class and just reference the Registry object, problably include an `__iter__` method.